# Change disk number in Disk Management for PCIe SSD and SATA HDD

Tags: windows, windows-10, pci-express

It's not a big issue but I find it quite annoying.

My SSD has OS and is PCI NVMe, while 2nd disk is SATA HDD. For some reason, Window detect them in reverse order with 0 = HDD, 1 = SSD. Is it possible to fix this order in Disk Management as well as Task Manager.

Comment: AFAIK No, this depends on the intermal enumeration of busses and devices evtentually also IRQs and how the mainboard uses them.

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible by :

- Switching disk connectors, but unfortunately NVMe & SATA are not compatible.
- As an option in the BIOS/UEFI if it exists.

Updating the BIOS/UEFI might possibly help (very remote possibility),
although this is a dangerous operation.
Any problem during the update could cause the computer to brick,
so is not worth it for only an annoyance.
Especially since this order might be built-into the motherboard.